# I am getting error in INotifyPropertyChanged Property in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

**Code Behind File:**

```
namespace WindowsTrainingTasks
{
    public interface INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
    public class SampleViewModel :INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _name="Johnson";
        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return _name;
            }
            set
            {
                _name = value;
                onPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
        private string _mobile="9876543210";
        public string Mobile
        {
            get
            {
                return _mobile;
            }
            set
            {
                _mobile = value;
                onPropertyChanged("Mobile");
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void onPropertyChanged(string property)
        {
                 PropertyChangedEventHandler _PropertyChanged = PropertyChanged;
                _PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
        public SampleViewModel()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What's the error? Without an error description, we can only guess...

Comment: Why you declared own INotifyPropertyChanged interface? You should use standard .NET implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged in your WPF application.

Comment: Why are you creating your own 'INotifyPropertyChanged' interface??? Its part of the System.ComponentModel namespace, use that one instead.

Comment: As stated by both AndreyAkinshin and Bablo you are declaring the INotiftyPropertyChanged interface inside your own namespace, which will be used to absolutely no effect at all. INotiftyPropertyChanged is an existing framework interface, used to tell the UI that a property has changed (or all properties if String.Empty is used as args) and force a redraw of the given property. When you are using your own interface, there will be no signalling to the gui.

Comment: I've added your attempted edit back in to your question where it belongs. This is exactly the error you will get that I told you about in my answer. Also take note of the cooment from @Stian. above - your bindings won't update if you use your own INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why you've chosen to declare your own INotifyPropertyChanged interface - it's already [in the framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Additionally you need to do a null check before invoking the delegates on the event:

```
public void onPropertyChanged(string property)
{
    var _PropertyChanged = PropertyChanged;
    if (_PropertyChanged != null)
        _PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
}
```

otherwise if nothing has been registered for the event then you will get a [NullReferenceException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullreferenceexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: yeah ok. now i removed the interface and now am getting no error but i dont know what format i can get the output because am new to inotifypropertychanged so anyone explain this with output.

Comment: What do you mean "what output"? That is a different question that you need to ask separately.

Comment: i know the concept of INotifyPropertyChanged but i dont have the practical knowledge of it. Thats why, am asking the full coding with their output..

Comment: Any function that is registered as a handler for that event will receive the property name and the object that the event occurred on as its parameters. The first link I included has a good example - check it out.